# How to call a variable function in php within a class?

Tags: php, function

I have the following example code

```
<?php

class Test {
    function foo() {
        print "foo\n";
    }

    function bar() {
        $func = 'foo';
        $func();
    }
}

$test = new Test();
$test->bar()
```

which calls `$test-bar()`, whiich internally calls a variable php function named `foo`. This variable contains the string `foo` and I want the function `foo` be called [like here](http://php.net/manual/en/functions.variable-functions.php). Instead of getting the expected output

```
foo
```

I get an error:

```
PHP Fatal error:  Call to undefined function foo()  ...
```

How to do this right, when using a string for the function-name? The string 'func' might denote several different functions inside the class scope in the actual code.

According to [the doc](http://php.net/manual/en/functions.variable-functions.php) the above should work like I have coded, more or less...

Comment: 0_0 How about using data structures rather than horrors like `$func = 'foo'; $func();`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
<?php

class Test {
    public function foo() {
        print "foo\n";
    }

    public function bar() {
        $func = 'foo';
        $this->$func();
    }
}

$test = new Test();
$test->bar();

?>
```

Use this for accessing the current function of this class

Comment: Thanks, that is what I was looking for. Maybe someone could add this to the php docs...?

Answer (score 0):

You use the keyword `$this`

```
<?php

class Test {
    function foo() {
        print "foo\n";
    }

    function bar() {
        $this->foo(); //  you can do this

    }
}

$test = new Test();
$test->bar()
```

There are two ways to call a method from a string input:

```
$methodName = "foo";
$this->$methodName();
```

Or you can use call_user_func_array()

```
call_user_func_array("foo",$args); // args is an array of your arguments
```

or

```
call_user_func_array(array($this,"foo"),$args); // will call the method in this scope
```

Comment: I do not want to call the function directly, I need a string with the function's name. I have updated the question to make this point clear. Sorry.

Answer (score 0):

What you can do is use the function `call_user_func()` to invoke the callback.

```
<?php

class Test {
    public function foo() {
        print "foo\n";
    }

    public function bar() {
        $func = 'foo';
        call_user_func(array($this, $func));
    }
}

$test = new Test();
$test->bar();
```